# Is every episode of "Where are my Pants?" identical?

Tags: lego, lego-cinematic-universe, the-lego-movie

In *The Lego Movie* (2014), it seems to be a running gag that the in-world TV show "Where are my Pants?" consists solely of the main (pantsless) character asking his wife "Honey, where are my pants?" in every episode, with the 'pants' part drawn out comically. In the later part of the movie (after we have been introduced to the show), the main characters apparently crash the show's actual film set and we see the actors in the act of performing that same gag, implying that they are simply re-filming the same scene for the next episode. There is also an implication that much in-world pop culture is intended to have brainwashing effects, which the Master Builders oppose.

*In-world*, is the show "Where are my Pants?" solely a repeat of the same gag in every episode?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It would appear to be the same joke just in different situations. The LEGO website advertising the [“Where Are My Pants?” Guy Minifigure](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/minifigures/characters/where-are-my-pants-guy-3ff8084aaed944e49c69b62dd212fddb) has the following to say:

> The story about “Where Are My Pants?” Guy from LEGO® Minifigures
>
> “Honey, where are my pants?”
>
> The “Where Are My Pants?” Guy is the star of the #1 hit television show “Where Are My Pants?”, written, filmed, and broadcast by the Octan Studios subsidiary of President Business’s personal mega-corporation.
>
> Every night, the citizens of Bricksburg tune in to watch the show and laugh at the crazy situations that this pantsless fellow finds himself in, and every morning, they all gather at their office water coolers to chat about their favorite moments from the latest episode. Little do they know that the show is slowly sapping their creativity and imagination – just like President Business wants!

From my reading of this it says "pantless fellow" implying he is always pantless and so the same joke is repeated. The "crazy situations" part also implies it isn't the exact same episode but altered slightly each day with a new situation. As the above quote notes this would be in line with what President Business wants as he wants to zap the creativity.

Comment: Or parody of where is my supersuit from Incredibles?

Comment: @Oni Probably not. At the time it was made, virtually no-one remembered the Incredibles. That's only become a thing due to the marketing around the sequel.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 that's even more speculative than the first commenter.

Answer (score 0):

It's an inside joke for people that put lego sets together. The tops are always easy to spot but the bottoms always blend in with other brick

Comment: I'm assuming that this answer is correct in upvoting it, regardless: welcome to Scifi, enjoy our [tour] and refer to the [help] when you would like guidance as to our ways.

Comment: Any evidence you can provide, maybe a link and quote from a Lego site about the difficulty of funding the pants, would help.